# Number of ways N circles of different radius can be arranged in a line

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Question: Given M points on a line separated by 11 unit. Find the number of ways N circles of different radii can be drawn so that they don't intersect or overlap or one inside another?? Provided that the centers of circles should be those MM points.

Example 1: N=3,M=6,r1=1,r2=1,r3=1 Answer: 24 ways.

Example 2: N=2,M=5 ,r1=1,r2=2 Answer: 6 ways.

Example 3: N=1,M=10,r=50. Answer =10 ways.

I found this question online and have not been able to solve it till now. Till now I have been able to only work up this much that any circle can take spaces from n−rn−r to n−2rn−2r. But among other issues how can I adjust for edge cases in which a circle with radius 33 takes n−4n−4th point, now the last point will be left untouched but I cannot place any circle with a radius greater than 1. I am not able to see any generalized mathematical solution to this.

Comment: do You mean 1 unit?

Comment: Just plain backtracking?

Answer (score 0):

If the center of the circles can be placed on non-integer x and y coordinates, then it is either impossible due to the length being too short, or infinitely many due to have enough length and there are infinitely many translations.

So, since you have to compute the results, I will assume that the coordinates of (M,M) are integer numbers.

If there is a single circle, then the solution is the number of points the circle can be legally placed.

If there are at least two circles, then you need to calculate the sum of the diameters and if that happens to be larger than the total length of the line we are speaking about, then you have no solution. If that is not the case, then you need to subtract the sum of diameters from the total length, getting Complementer. You also have N! permutations to compute the order of the circles. And you will have Complementer - 1 possible locations where you can distribute the gaps between the circles. The lengths of the gaps are G1, ..., Gn-1

We know that G1 + ... + Gn-1 = Complementer

The number of possible distributions of G1, ..., Gn-1 is D. The formula therefore would b

N! * D

The remaining question is: how can we compute D?

Solution:

```
function distr(depth, maxDepth, amount)
    if (depth = maxDepth) then
        return 1 //we need to put the remaining elements on the last slot
    end if
    sum = 1 //if we put amount here, that is a trivial case
    for i = amount - 1 to 0 do
        sum = distr(depth + 1, maxDepth, amount - i)
    end for
    return sum
end distr
```

You need to call distr with depth = 1, maxDepth = N-1, amout = Complementer

Comment: I think I might not have communicated the idea properly. Look at example 3. There are 10 points and only one circle, so you can place the circle at 10 different points. If you are the first or the last in row, then the diameter exceeding the total value doesn't matter

Comment: @ambikeyasangwan that case was actually dealt with in this answer. Quote: "If there is a single circle, then the solution is the number of points the circle can be legally placed."

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the complementers please?

Comment: @ambikeyasangwan yes, of course. I named Complementer the number of unfilled legal points where you could place a circle. If you have 11 points for example, but the sum of the diameters is 5, for example, then you will have 6 unused slots and you need to calculate the number of ways you combine those slots. I have described an algorithm for this called distr. I am pretty sure I could give a formula for that but I have not enough time to do that now.

Comment: Also, wouldn't  N! be too large for computers to process? I mean values around 100 or so probably exceed the range of long. Is there a more computational friendly version?

Comment: @ambikeyasangwan that is the formula. You can avoid calculating the actual result of n! and store it as the product of several prime numbers on given powers or you can write your class to deal with large numbers or you can use implementations for large numbers, like BigInteger in Java. Anyway, those technicalities are outside the scope of this question which deals with algorithms.